# First time slow on IIS7.5+asmx

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, iis

I have a question about first time slow on IIS7.5+ASP.NET model.

Under my website, a asmx file works for synchronize data between server and a client machine.
Now I found if a client machine doesn't do any action with server for a long time such like 1 hour or more, then at the first time synchronizing, data will lost. After the first time, everything seems fine.

I did some researches on this issue and I think it is the problem relates to IIS First Time Slow, followed some suggestions and tried to put

```
< generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/ >
```

under Framework Aspnet.config file but it doesn't really help. Also I tried to disable IdleTime runout but not really help.

Comment: What do your app pool recycling settings look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to pre-compile your application. Use the [asp.net compilation tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx)

Everytime IIS recycles the app-pool, it has to compile your web project / web service again on the next hit, which takes some time.
You can find more information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Also, make sure you have disable debug mode on your production web.config